# Find min across multiple columns seperately

Tags: mysql

My gut tells me there is already an answer for this but I can't find one, at least for [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Please correct me if I'm wrong and I'll delete this post.

I have a table with ID as prime key, three numeric columns (lets call them A, B, C) and four columns (call them W, X, Y, Z) I need to group on.

For each group there will be one ID (of many) where A is lowest, B is lowest and C is lowest. So, this is not 'get the lowest from multiple columns', I need first to work out the min of A for each group, then B for each from the ID's narrowed down by getting the min of A, and then C for each from the remaining choices after the min of B. Then, get the ID that relates to this combination for each grouping (there will only be one). E.g

```
| ID | A | B | C | W | X | Y | Z | 
----------------------------------
| 1  | 2 | 5 | 5 | D | E | F | G | <-- first group
| 2  | 1 | 5 | 4 | D | E | F | G | 
| 3  | 1 | 5 | 3 | D | E | F | G |
| 4  | 1 | 2 | 4 | H | I | J | K | <-- second group
| 5  | 2 | 5 | 4 | H | I | J | K |
```

Expected output:

```
| ID | A | B | C | W | X | Y | Z | 
----------------------------------

| 3  | 1 | 5 | 3 | D | E | F | G | <-- first group min
| 4  | 1 | 2 | 4 | H | I | J | K | <-- second group min
```

I thought to try making three separate queries to get each of the min values then join on each of the group columns but I get more than one result for each group. I've tried a subquery too but I guess its the same issue:

```
select ID, A
from tbl
where A= (select min(A) from tbl as m where m.W= tbl.W
.... and so on
```

Happy to read up and solve this myself if anyone can provide a link as my Google-Fu is letting me down.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple of ways, here is what worked out well out of them:

```
select id,A,B,C,W,X,Y,Z from
(select * from `table` inner join 
(SELECT min(A) as U,min(B) as I,min(C) as O,W as `G`,X as `H`,Y as `J`,Z as `K` FROM `table`
group by G,H,J,K) as temp on temp.U=`table`.A and temp.I=`table`.B and temp.O=`table`.C) as temp2
```

I know it's a little messy but it gets the desired result.